# Класс с собственным типом данных C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Всем привет, можете помочь c задачей?
Задание: написать класс на с#, который реализует собственный тип данных(мера веса т-кг-г), при этом объекты класса должны поддерживать операции +,-,*,/, сравнение, вывод на экран, округление. 
Пример моего кода:

```
class Calculator {
    public object Num1 { get; set; }
    public object Num2 { get; set; }

    void Sum(int Num1, int Num2)        //операции
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {3}", Num1, Num2, Num1 + Num2);
    }
    void Sub(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", Num1, Num2, Num1 - Num2);
    }
    void Multi(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", Num1, Num2, Num1 * Num2);
    }
    void Division(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", Num1, Num2, Num1 / Num2);
    }

    void Compare(int Num1, int Num2)     //сравнение
    {
        if (Num1 > Num2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is grater than {1}", Num1, Num2);
        }
        if(Num2 > Num1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is grater than {1}", Num2, Num1);
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Num {0}, and {1} - are equal", Num1, Num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: От вас скорей всего не это хотят, а [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading). И как ваш код "реализует собственный тип данных(мера веса т-кг-г)"? Лично я вижу простой "Калькулятор". Да и от нас тогда что вы хотите?

Comment: Спасибо, просто не мог разобраться чего конкретно от меня хотят